# How to make image responsive when window resizes? CSS & HTML5

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want the image that I'm using to be to the right of a paragraph during normal window size. This I don't have an issue with.

But when I make the window smaller, I run into this issue:

[image]

The image is on top of the text when the browser size is reduced. 
**When the page is reduced, I would like the image to be aligned under the text.**

```css
.soon {
  margin: 30px;
}

.leafPic {
  margin-left: 60%;
  margin-top: -15%;
}

@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
  .img {
    width: auto\9;
    /* ie8 */
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="soon">
  <h2>LLORUM ISPUS DOR!</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate dolorem reprehenderit illo officia<br> ex quidem aut veniam modi numquam iusto, ipsam placeat dolorum quae eum vero! Eveniet esse<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
    elit. Voluptate dolorem reprehenderit illo officia<br> enim molestiae delectus modi officiis ab porro, maiores, dolores consequuntur ipsum expedita!Lorem <br> ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate dolorem reprehenderit illo
    officia<br> ex quidem aut veniam modi numquam iusto, ipsam placeat dolorum quae eum vero! Eveniet esse<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate dolorem reprehenderit illo officia<br> enim molestiae delectus modi officiis
    ab porro, maiores, dolores consequuntur ipsum expedita!</p>
</section>

<div class="leafPic">
  <img src="bloomingflower.png" height="350" width="500" alt="Blooming flower">
</div>
```

Comment: I just made a runnable snippet for you and I suggest you edit your post again to add a valid link for the image (upload it to imgur for example).

Comment: With Grids it's fairly easy to manage @media queries for items placement. You can check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Pi_L/vwb1p6yh/) where i modified your code.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to reset the `margin-left` to `0` on `div.leafPic`.

> for demo purposes, I used a [placeholder image](https://placeholder.com) so the intended result can be seen. Reset the `img`'s `src` attribute to your image's path.

```css
.soon {
  margin: 30px;
}

.leafPic {
  margin-left: 60%;
  margin-top: -15%;
}

.leafPic img {
  height: 350px;
  width: 500px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
  .leafPic {
    margin-left: 0; /** reset **/
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="soon">
  <h2>LLORUM ISPUS DOR!</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate dolorem reprehenderit illo officia<br> ex quidem aut veniam modi numquam iusto, ipsam placeat dolorum quae eum vero! Eveniet esse<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
    elit. Voluptate dolorem reprehenderit illo officia<br> enim molestiae delectus modi officiis ab porro, maiores, dolores consequuntur ipsum expedita!Lorem <br> ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate dolorem reprehenderit illo
    officia
    <br> ex quidem aut veniam modi numquam iusto, ipsam placeat dolorum quae eum vero! Eveniet esse<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate dolorem reprehenderit illo officia<br> enim molestiae delectus modi officiis ab
    porro, maiores, dolores consequuntur ipsum expedita!</p>
</section>

<div class="leafPic">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350" alt="Blooming flower">
</div>
```